# Examples of norms essentially different from $p$-norms

Tags: normed-spaces

I'm looking for examples of norms that can be applied to finite-dimensional vectors but are not just $p$-norms or trivial variations of them. The ones I've found - the norms in [James' space](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/James%27_space) or [Tsirelson's space](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Tsirelson_space) - only make sense for infinite dimensions.

To be more precise, I'm looking for norms which are *not* of the form $\|v\| := \|Av\|_p$ for some positive definite matrix $A$, or $\|v\| := \lambda \|v\|_p + (1-\lambda)\|v\|_q$.

The only example I've found so far is the norm defined as $$ \|v\|^{(k)} := \sum_{i=1}^k \max_j{}^{\!(i)} |v_j|,$$ where $\max^{(i)}$ is the $i$th largest element.

There must be more interesting norms. Any ideas?

Comment: Have you considered the various [matrix norms](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Matrix_norm)? Matrices are finite-dimensional vectors, after all.

Comment: Yes, I have. But to get an interesting matrix norm you'd need to reshape the vector into a rectangular matrix, which will only work if the dimension is not a prime number, or if you pad the vector with zeroes until the dimension is nice. I was hoping for something less contrived.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I still would like to have some more "natural" examples of such norms, specifically those with smooth and permutation-symmetric unit balls. Using the [Minkowski functional](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Minkowski_functional), as explained by Jeff, allows me to define a norm from any convex body which is closed, convex, and symmetric. Playing around I found two nice unit balls. One is

$$ K_\text{exp} = \{x \in \mathbb R^n: \frac{1}{e+n-1}\sum_{i=1}^n e^{x_i^2} \le 1\},$$
for which it is really difficult to calculate the corresponding norm $\|\cdot\|_\text{exp}$ for any non-trivial vector. The cases I could solve analytically are
$$\|1^{(n)}\|_\text{exp} = \frac{1}{\sqrt{\log(1+(e-1)/n)}}$$
where $1^{(n)}$ is the vector of all ones,
and for the vector $(1,\sqrt{2})$ we have
$$\|(1,\sqrt{2})\|_\text{exp} = \frac{1}{\sqrt{\log(-\frac12+\frac12\sqrt{5+4e})}}.$$
The other unit ball is 
$$ K_\text{log} = \{x \in \mathbb R^n: \frac12\prod_{i=1}^n(1+x_i^2)\le 1\},$$
for which I also couldn't get a general formula for an arbitrary vector. For the vector of all ones we have
$$\|1^{(n)}\|_\text{log} = \frac{1}{\sqrt{\sqrt[n]{2}-1}},$$
and for an arbitrary 2-dimensional vector $(x,y)$ we have
$$\|(x,y)\|_\text{log} = \frac1{\sqrt2}\sqrt{x^2+y^2+\sqrt{x^4+6x^2y^2+y^4}}.$$

Answer (score 7):

A norm is uniquely determined by its unit ball, and conversely, you can define a norm to have any unit ball you like. The construction goes like this. Let $K\subset \mathbb{R}^n$ be a closed, bounded, convex, and symmetric set ($x\in K$ if and only if $-x\in K$). Define

$$\|x\|_K = \inf\{\lambda > 0 \, |\, x \in \lambda K\}.$$

This is called the Minkowski functional, and $\|\cdot \|_K$ is a semi-norm. If you also assume $K$ contains an open neighborhood of the origin, then $\|\cdot \|_K$ is a norm, and the unit ball for the norm is exactly $K$.

So basically you can select any $K$ (within reason) and define a norm for which $K$ is the unit ball. Every norm can be constructed in this way, so it is very general and generates "new" norms that are not just $p$ norms.

As an example, let $X_m$ be a collection of $m$ independent and identically distributed random variables $\mathbb{R}^n$ with a Lebesgue density, and set

$$K_m = \text{ConvexHull} (-X_m \cup X_m).$$

Then define the norm $\|x\|_{K_m}$. This is a norm with a unit ball that is a random convex polytope (provided $2m \geq n+1$).

A concrete example is the $n$-dimensional polytope with vertices of the form $$\frac{1}{\sqrt k} \sum_{i=1}^k s_{\sigma(i)} e_{\sigma(i)}$$ for all $k \le n$, all signs $s$ and permutations $\sigma$. It has $\sum_{i=1}^n {n \choose i}2^i$ vertices.

Comment: Can you add a concrete example of an interesting $K$?

Comment: There are an infinity of possible examples; I don't know what you find interesting. I added an example where the unit ball is a random polytope.

Comment: Yes, there is an infinity of possible examples, this is exactly the problem. "Interesting" is left for you to decide, but I had something more concrete in mind than a random polytope.

Comment: Make it concrete by selecting the points $X_m$ yourself; anything is fine as long as they are affinely independent. Or choose your favorite convex set and off you go.

Comment: Of course I could do that, and end up with a norm that is a pain in the ass to evaluate, and really hard to prove anything about.

Comment: You did not specify you wanted a norm that is easy to evaluate. And what do you want to prove about it? The Minkowski functional is a useful tool in functional analysis precisely because it is easier to use in certain proofs.

Comment: The Minkowski functional is great, thanks for telling me about it. What I'm complaining about is the generalness of $K$. Maybe it is a cultural difference, what physicists think count as a nice example, and what mathematicians think count as a nice example.

Specifically, I wanted to find a nice norm for which the theorem by Bohnenblust discussed [here](https://mathoverflow.net/questions/292322/which-norms-on-vectors-can-be-consistently-decomposed) does not hold, and more generally explore norms that could provide alternatives to the Born rule.

Comment: @MateusAraújo Jeff answered *exactly* your question as it was formulated above. Even more, he gave you a tool to find *all* norms. Which are "essentially different" or "interesting" is up to you. Almost all norms described this way are unlike the $p$-norms, e.g. taking as unit circle a regular polygon on even many sides. Either you edit the question or you post a new qustion with your actual restriction. Because I see no way to answer this one other than Jeff did.

Comment: @M.Winter, if you want to be pedantic, Jeff didn't provide a single example, just a general strategy to generate examples. One does need to instantiate it. Contrast with Felix Klein, which did write out two well-defined norms (although he neglected to prove that it was not of the undesired form.).

Comment: I suppose then you do not consider $\|x\|_p:= (\sum |x_i|^p)^{1/p}$ an example of a norm until it is instantiated by choosing a value for $p$?

Comment: @MateusAraújo Here is an *explicit* example. Let $K$ be a hexagon (e.g. centered at the origin, side length $1$, vertices on the $x$-axis). Then $\|x\|_K := \inf\{\lambda > 0 \, |\, x \in \lambda K\}$ is a formula for such a "different" norm. Since $p$-norms do not have hexagonal unit circles, it's even "essentially different". Do you need anything else?

Comment: Yes, @M.Winter, this is all I want. It is easy, just a couple of lines that need to be added to the answer. Nothing to fight about. Jeff, if I edit your answer to include an explicit $n$-dimensional polytope will you accept the edit?

Comment: Sure, go ahead.

Comment: Thanks, it's there.

Answer (score 2):

Take any norm $\nu$ on a function space and then define
$$\Vert(a_1,\ldots,a_n)\Vert=\nu\left(t\mapsto\sum_{k=1}^na_kt^{k-1}\right).$$
For example
$$\Vert(a_1,\ldots,a_n)\Vert=\sup_{t\in[0,1]}\left\vert\sum_{k=1}^na_kt^{k-1}\right\vert$$
Or
$$\Vert(a_1,\ldots,a_n)\Vert=\int_{0}^1\left\vert\sum_{k=1}^na_kt^{k-1}\right\vert \omega(t) dt$$
For some positive weight $\omega$.

Comment: I haven't done a proof, but I'm pretty sure both your examples reduce to $\|v\|=\|Av\|_p$ for some positive definite matrix $A$.

Comment: I doubt this is the case, especially with the first example where $\nu$ is arbitrary.

Comment: I think you missed the "both of your examples" part of my sentence.

Comment: I still doubt either example is in the form you suggested. If you think it is, give a proof.

Comment: Well, Felix Klein is the one proposing this as an example of a norm which is not of the undesired form, I think the burden of proof lies with him.